# Can I use Appium run test for other's app?

Tags: android, ios, testing, appium

Can i use Appium to test an app that i download, which were not developed and package on my mac?

I try to do this on an iOS app. But when I Launch it, it crash immediately every time.

Why? And is it possible on Android? Thanks for help.

Comment: iOS apps can be automated even if they are not developed and bundled on local machine. You need to have *.ipa file for the downloaded app. App crash can happen due to multiple reasons. What exactly is the error you are getting? In android, you can download the app, and can share its *.apk file via programs like appshare.

Answer (score 4):

You can do so with Android apps if you have the `.apk` file.

But it is impossible with iOS apps because they must be signed with developer identity from XCode application when building the `.ipa` file. Otherwise it will not run on Appium.